# Python Regex match or potential match

Tags: python, regex

## Question:

How do I use Python's regular expression module (`re`) to determine if a match has been made, or that a potential match could be made?

## Details:

I want a regex pattern which searches for a pattern of words in a correct order regardless of what's between them. I want a function which returns `Yes` if found, `Maybe` if a match could still be found or `No` if no match can be found. We are looking for the pattern `One|....|Two|....|Three`, here are some examples (Note the names, their count, or their order are not important, all I care about is the three words `One`, `Two` and `Three`, and the acceptable words in between are `John`, `Malkovich`, `Stamos` and `Travolta`).

**Returns YES:**

```
One|John|Malkovich|Two|John|Stamos|Three|John|Travolta
```

**Returns YES:**

```
One|John|Two|John|Three|John
```

**Returns YES:**

```
One|Two|Three
```

**Returns MAYBE:**

```
One|Two
```

**Returns MAYBE:**

```
One
```

**Returns NO:**

```
Three|Two|One
```

I understand the examples are not airtight, so here is what I have for the regex to get YES:

```
if re.match('One\|(John\||Malkovich\||Stamos\||Travolta\|)*Two\|(John\||Malkovich\||Stamos\||Travolta\|)*Three\|(John\||Malkovich\||Stamos\||Travolta\|)*', 'One|John|Malkovich|Two|John|Stamos|Three|John|Travolta') != None
   return 'Yes'
```

Obviously if the pattern is `Three|Two|One` the above will fail, and we can return `No`, but how do I check for the `Maybe` case? I thought about nesting the parentheses, like so (note, not tested)

```
if re.match('One\|((John\||Malkovich\||Stamos\||Travolta\|)*Two(\|(John\||Malkovich\||Stamos\||Travolta\|)*Three\|(John\||Malkovich\||Stamos\||Travolta\|)*)*)*', 'One|John|Malkovich|Two|John|Stamos|Three|John|Travolta') != None
   return 'Yes'
```

But I don't think that will do what I want it to do.

## More Details:

I am not actually looking for `Travoltas` and `Malkovichs` (shocking, I know). I am matching against inotify Patterns such as `IN_MOVE`, `IN_CREATE`, `IN_OPEN`, and  I am logging them and getting hundreds of them, then I go in and then look for a particular pattern such as `IN_ACCESS`...`IN_OPEN`....`IN_MODIFY`, but in some cases I don't want an `IN_DELETE` after the `IN_OPEN` and in others I do. I'm essentially pattern matching to use inotify to detect when *text editors gone wild* and they try to crush programmers souls by doing a temporary-file-swap-save instead of just modifying the file. I don't want to free up those logs instantly, but I only want to hold on to them for as long as is necessary. `Maybe` means dont erase the logs. `Yes` means do something then erase the log and `No` means don't do anything but still erase the logs. As I will have multiple rules for each program (ie. `vim` v `gedit` v `emacs`) I wanted to use a regular expression which would be more human readable and easier to write then creating a massive tree, or as user [Joel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1142167/joel-cornett) suggested, just going over the words with a loop

Comment: Are you sure using regular expressions is the correct approach? One could simply `[word for word in text.split() if word in wordList]` and then check the order of that list.

Comment: What would `Two|Three` return? Or `One|Three`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I added more info, but I am looking for exactly the pattern `One|Two|Three` among a certain amount of acceptable noise (`John`, `Stamos`...)

Comment: Are your "maybe" matches always going to be at the end of the string?

Comment: @JoelCornett I'm not too sure what you mean

Comment: What is `Three|Two|One|Two|Three|Two|One`? MaybeYesMaybeNo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. - Jamie Zawinski

Perhaps an algorithm like this would be more appropriate. Here is some pseudocode.

```
matchlist.current = matchlist.first()
for each word in input
    if word = matchlist.current
        matchlist.current = matchlist.next() // assuming next returns null if at end of list
    else if not allowedlist.contains(word)
        return 'No'
if matchlist.current = null // we hit the end of the list
    return 'Yes'
return 'Maybe'
```

Comment: I think there's an error in your pseudocode. `=` in line 3 is for equality while in line 4 it is for assignment

Comment: @Joel: Have you upgraded to version 11.5 yet? It has a new feature that lets it figure out the intended meaning and transparently compile. ;)

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a regex for this. But it's definitely possible:

```
regex = re.compile(
    r"""^           # Start of string
    (?:             # Match...
     (?:            # one of the following:
      One()         # One (use empty capturing group to indicate match)
     |              # or
      \1Two()       # Two if One has matched previously
     |              # or
      \1\2Three()   # Three if One and Two have matched previously
     |              # or
      John          # any of the other strings
     |              # etc.
      Malkovich
     |
      Stamos
     |
      Travolta
     )              # End of alternation
     \|?            # followed by optional separator
    )*              # any number of repeats
    $               # until the end of the string.""", 
    re.VERBOSE)
```

Now you can check for YES and MAYBE by checking if you get a match at all:

```
>>> yes = regex.match("One|John|Malkovich|Two|John|Stamos|Three|John|Travolta")
>>> yes
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001F90620>
>>> maybe = regex.match("One|John|Malkovich|Two|John|Stamos")
>>> maybe
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001F904F0>
```

And you can differentiate between YES and MAYBE by checking whether all of the groups have participated in the match (i. e. are not `None`):

```
>>> yes.groups()
('', '', '')
>>> maybe.groups()
('', '', None)
```

And if the regex doesn't match at all, that's a NO for you:

```
>>> no = regex.match("Three|Two|One")
>>> no is None
True
```

Comment: This definitely does look to make matters much harder then would be with lists and trees